# Why beforeunload event is not working when i'm closing the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, browser

Below is my code...

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
    Actions.SendTimeOutEMail();                      
});
```

Actions.SendTimeOutEMail() is a flux action and will call an ajax function.

When I close the window tab in browser, it will run "Actions.SendTimeOutEMail"
, I checked it from my back-end server log.

However, if I close the browser itself, the event will not fire and I can't see the output of the event in the server log.

Why this behavior is different between click close of a tab and click close of browser?